# TensorFlow freeze_graph cannot find .runfiles

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have built TensorFlow from source using Bazel, however, when I try to run the freeze_graph script, I get the error requesting for the .runfiles

Here is my run command

```
python /home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=graph.pbtx --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001 --input_binary=false --output_graph=../frozen_graph/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=ArgMax
```

and here is the error it generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph", line 172, in <module>
Main()
File "/home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph", line 111, in Main
module_space = FindModuleSpace()
File "/home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph", line 86, in FindModuleSpace
raise AssertionError('Cannot find .runfiles directory for %s' % sys.argv[0])
AssertionError: Cannot find .runfiles directory for /home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used bazel to build freeze_graph, then bazel-bin contains your *compiled* freeze_graph code. This means you don't need to invoke freeze_graph with python, you can run it like this:

```
./home/olu/TensorFlow_Source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph  ...
```

You can run the python file directory by calling:

```
python /path/to/freeze_graph.py ...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes it did...Solved!

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I got the same error and I needed to build freeze_graph 1st:

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph
```

After this you can run it this way:

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
--input_graph=/tmp/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb \
--input_checkpoint=/tmp/checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt \
--input_binary=true --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_inception_v3.pb \
--output_node_names=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1`

David

Comment: Okay, great!. This will be helpful to someone else facing similar issues too